# How to use a Generic Set object in Java

Tags: java, oop, junit, set

I am having all kinds of issues with this assignment from my professor. She gave us some skeleton code and the Junit tests to make sure it is working correctly. We are not allowed to change any of the method names or parameters. I just need to know if I am on the right track here or if I am going in a bad direction.

```
public class MathSet<Key> {
// create a set
Key key;
int size;
HashSet<Key> yup = new HashSet<Key>();
public MathSet(Key[] universe) {
    // replace the throw statement with your implementation
}

// put key into the set
public void add(Key key) {
    // replace the throw statement with your implementation
    if(yup.contains(key)){
    }else {
        yup.add(key);
        size++;
    }
}

// return set of keys in the universe that are not in the set
public MathSet<Key> complement() {
    // replace the throw statement with your implementation
}

// put keys from the given set into this set that are not already there
public void union(MathSet<Key> set) {
    // replace the throw statement with your implementation
    for(Key key : set) {
        yup.add(key);
        size++;
    }
}

// remove any keys from this set that are not in the given set
public void intersection(MathSet<Key> set) {
    // replace the throw statement with your implementation
    HashSet<Key> ugh = new HashSet<Key>();
    ugh = set;
    for(Key key : ugh) {
        yup.remove(key);
        size--;
        
    }
}

// remove key from the set
public void delete(Key key) {
    // replace the throw statement with your implementation
    if(yup.contains(key)) {
        yup.remove(key);
        size--;
    }
}

// is the key in this set?
public boolean contains(Key key) {
    // replace the throw statement with your implementation
    if(yup.contains(key)) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

// is the set empty?
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // replace the throw statement with your implementation
    if(yup.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

// number of keys in the set
public int size() {
    // replace the throw statement with your implementation
    return size;
}
```

}

These are the tests that I am trying to make work.

```
class MathSetTest {

@Test
void test_1() {
    Integer[] universe = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    MathSet<Integer> uut = new MathSet<Integer>(universe);
    assertEquals(0, uut.size());
    assertTrue(uut.isEmpty());

    uut.add(1);
    assertEquals(1, uut.size());
    assertFalse(uut.isEmpty());

    uut.add(3);
    assertEquals(2, uut.size());
    assertFalse(uut.isEmpty());

    uut.add(3);
    assertEquals(2, uut.size());
    assertFalse(uut.isEmpty());

    assertTrue(uut.contains(3));
    assertFalse(uut.contains(9));

    uut.delete(10);
    assertEquals(2, uut.size());
    assertFalse(uut.isEmpty());

    uut.delete(1);
    assertEquals(1, uut.size());
    assertFalse(uut.isEmpty());

    uut.delete(3);
    assertEquals(0, uut.size());
    assertTrue(uut.isEmpty());
}

@Test
void test_2() {
    Character[] universe = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' };
    MathSet<Character> uut = new MathSet<Character>(universe);
    Character[] keys1 = { 'a', 'e', 'h' };
    Character[] keys2 = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g' };
    for (char key : keys1) {
        uut.add(key);
    }
    assertFalse(uut.isEmpty());
    assertEquals(3, uut.size());
    MathSet<Character> cSet = uut.complement();
    for (char key : keys1) {
        assertFalse(cSet.contains(key));
    }
    for (char key : keys2) {
        assertTrue(cSet.contains(key));
    }
}

@Test
void test_3() {
    Integer[] universe = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    MathSet<Integer> set1 = new MathSet<Integer>(universe);
    MathSet<Integer> set2 = new MathSet<Integer>(universe);

    Integer[] keys1 = { 1, 3, 6 };
    Integer[] keys2 = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    for (Integer key : keys1) {
        set1.add(key);
    }
    assertEquals(keys1.length, set1.size());

    for (Integer key : keys2) {
        set2.add(key);
    }
    assertEquals(keys2.length, set2.size());

    set1.union(set2);
    assertEquals(6, set1.size());

    for (Integer key : keys1) {
        assertTrue(set1.contains(key));
    }

    for (Integer key : keys2) {
        assertTrue(set1.contains(key));
    }
}

@Test
void test_4() {
    Integer[] universe = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    MathSet<Integer> set1 = new MathSet<Integer>(universe);
    MathSet<Integer> set2 = new MathSet<Integer>(universe);

    Integer[] keys1 = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 };
    Integer[] keys2 = { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    for (Integer key : keys1) {
        set1.add(key);
    }
    assertEquals(keys1.length, set1.size());

    for (Integer key : keys2) {
        set2.add(key);
    }
    assertEquals(keys2.length, set2.size());

    set1.intersection(set2);
    assertEquals(2, set1.size());

    for (Integer key : universe) {
        if (key == 2 || key == 8) {
            assertTrue(set1.contains(key));
        } else {
            assertFalse(set1.contains(key));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Compile errors:

Test 2- java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Cannot infer type arguments for MathSet<>

test 3- java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

test 4- java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from MathSet to HashSet

Comment: I think issue may be that you are passing `Integer` to `MathSet` which requires `Key` type and not `Integer`. If I have misunderstood, please add what is `Key` object. If you want `MathSet` to be generic, replace `Key` in `MathSet` with any other alphabet like `T` making it `MathSet<T>` and do other changes as needed.

Comment: @LUC1F3R The OP can use Key as a generic object type, even though that isn't standard. It does make it more difficult to understand, though. My first interpretation was like yours.

Comment: What are you having problems with? Are there compiler errors? If so, please tell us. Are there runtime exceptions? If so, please paste the full stack trace into the question. Does the output differ from your expectations? If so, please paste your input, your expected output, and you actual output. Please don't handicap the people trying to help you.

Comment: @NomadMaker completely agree but the reason for that suggestion was that if Key is meant to be used as generic then too, OP needs to use object of `Key` for `MathSet` operations, something like `Key<Integer> key1 = new Key(1)` and then use `key1` further.

Comment: Just consider that we do not know what “all kinds of issues” are. Besides that, I’m wondering whether implementing a Set by using an already existing implementation of Set isn’t kind of cheating, as almost all of those methods are redundant. You could get rid of the remaining bits by using `yup.size()` instead of maintaining your own `size` field. But if you keep it, you don’t need constructs like `if(yup.contains(key)){ }else { yup.add(key); size++; }`, you can simply use `if(yup.add(key)) size++;` and that’s it. But you must use it in `union` as well.

Comment: @NomadMaker Sorry, I am so used to seeing the errors in Eclipse did not really think about it. One of the main things I am having a problem with I think is the first function which is supposed to be the one that is creating the MathSet<key> object. I think if I can figure that out the rest will be a bit easier to wrap my head around. In the test, you can see that it is making a MathSet object, but my main question is am I providing the pieces to create the object correctly? Sorry if this is unclear I am trying my best.

Comment: @NomadMaker When I run the tests I do get errors, some from not having methods filled in others with things like "Can only iterate over java.lang.iterable." in the case of intersection it says can not convert from MathSet<Key> to HashSet<Key>. Which I think means that I have not built the object correctly.

Comment: Yes. Please edit your question to include your compiler errors.

Comment: @NomadMaker added compile errors

Comment: @LUC1F3R As stated above I am unable to change any of the names or parameters.